# jQuery: .toggle nth-of-type with a click of nth-of-type?

Tags: jquery, click, toggle

I'm trying to build a very simple mobile site where a content box toggles in with the click of its related button, and out with the click of either of the other buttons.

This code works to toggle every content box at the same time, even thought I only want the one related to the button I clicked:

```
$('#buttonBar > .button:nth-of-type(1)').click(function(){
  $('.content').toggle(500);
});
```

So, as soon as I tell it to toggle only its related content (nth-of-type(1)), nothing toggles at all:

```
$('#buttonBar > .button:nth-of-type(1)').click(function(){
  $('#buttonBar > .content:nth-of-type(1)').toggle(500);
});
```

Why does it just stop working here? Can I not use nth-of-type this way? If I can just figure out why I run into problems at this point, I can handle the rest.

Here is the project on CodePen: [HELP!](http://codepen.io/exomniac/pen/tLdne)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is a need to use :nth-of-type

```
var $contents = $('.content');
$('#buttonBar > .button').click(function () {
    var $next = $(this).next().stop(true).toggle(500);
    $contents.not($next).stop(true).hide(500)
});
```

Demo: [CodePen](http://codepen.io/arunpjohny/pen/lsgfA)

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
$('#buttonBar > .button:nth-of-type(1)').click(function(){
  $(this).toggle(500);
});
```

`this` refers to the clicked element.